# KDE Plasma 5. GUI elements lag terribly after large compiles. Lag is so bad the computer must be rebooted with a script

Tags: nvidia, kde, freeze, kde5

Every time I compile a model in Simulink, the GUI elements of the  "OS" GUI (roughly KDE Plasma elements) will begin to lag terribly, making the computer unusable. The lagging persists until the OS is rebooted. Since I cannot access the logout portions, I had to create a bash script that reboots the computer from a terminal.  I have suffered through many months due to this already.  I have completely overhauled the entire OS to 22.04,  added HWE, and the newest kernel 6.5.0   The lagging still persists.   I have performed heat monitoring, monitored `ps aux`,  monitored `free -h` , monitored `top`.  monitored free GPU memory with `nvidia-smi`.  Sorted processes by CPU usage.  I can detect no problems from those.  I am at my wits end.

```
xpswhite@machine:~$ uname -a
Linux X.X.X 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

xpswhite@machine:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

xpswhite@machine:~$ hwe-support-status --verbose
Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2027.

xpswhite@machine:~$ dkms status
nvidia/535.161.07, 5.15.0-100-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.161.07, 5.15.0-97-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/535.161.07, 6.5.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed

xpswhite@machine:~$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.15.3
KDE Frameworks: 5.104.0
kf5-config: 1.0

xpswhite@machine:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Mar 12 20:59:48 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.161.07             Driver Version: 535.161.07   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   34C    P8               9W / 220W |    409MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1276      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          165MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2068      G   /usr/bin/kwin_x11                             3MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2183      G   /usr/bin/plasmashell                         78MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2610      G   ...irefox/3941/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      143MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the majority of RAM is getting used up when you compile the model, and the computer is swapping system programs, and most likely this is not an Nvidia issue. But since swap is slow, it is causing issues. Also, even after you are done with Simulink, the OS does not move the contents of SWAP to RAM, so the freezing persists until the computer is rebooted.

If swapping is the case, then using zram-swap can be a very effective workaround. zram swap compresses memory, and it stores it into RAM itself (which is way faster than even an SSD).

First, disable swap. Most likely, you don't have a swap partition, but Ubuntu automatically created a swapfile. To disable it, open `/etc/fstab`, and comment out the line for swapfile.

Run `sudo nano /etc/fstab`, and add a `#` (to comment out) at the beginning of the line that begins with `/swapfile`

After commenting out, the line should look like the following

```
#/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Afterwards, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to save the file, followed by <kbd>y</kbd> to confirm saving.

To set up zram-swap, run the following commands.

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/foundObjects/zram-swap.git
cd zram-swap && sudo ./install.sh
```

Afterwards, reboot, and the problem should be gone.